# Problems with preg_match_all accepting string

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I can't get preg_match_all to fetch a span with a class and an attribute.

This is what i want to fetch/catch:

```
<span class="class-name" data-is-compact="false">Content</span>
```

This is what i've come up with:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://twitter.com/' . $this->twitter_sreenname . '/');    
preg_match_all('#<span class=\"class-name\" data-is-compact=\"false\">(.+?)\<\/span\>#', $response, $matches);
```

But i won't work.
If i remove:

```
data-is-compact=\"false\"
```

it works. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try including the actual string you're trying to match so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Sorry, i made a typing error, i meant a span instead of a div.
The string is the span.
I'm still quite new at this, so i might be using the wrong expressions - but it is the span that preg_match_all won't read/accept

Comment: I mean the actual value of `$response`. Without that, there is no way of telling what goes wrong.

Comment: Hi @StevenDon, i have just added the response

Comment: While you should go with the DOM answer below, there is nothing strictly wrong with your regex, although all the escapes in there are not strictly necessary. Trying it on a twitter page does give me the responses, assuming `class-name` is actually `ProfileNav-value`. At any rate, use the DOM for this. Regexes are notoriously bad for handling HTML content (which allows nesting and attributes can be reordered, to list just two of the pitfalls).

Comment: @Steven Don - not strictly necessary or strictly unnecessary?

Answer (score 3):

You don't use the good tool for that. Use the DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTMLFile('https://twitter.com/' . $this->twitter_sreenname . '/');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$query = '//span[@class="class-name" and @data-is-compact="false"]/text()';
$nodes = $xpath->query($query);

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 congratulations for answering quicker than the first person to suggest a regular expression.